# download image from JSON url with urllib

Tags: python, json, urllib

and thanks for reading this post.

I would like to download an image from JSON url, and i don't understand why the 
retrieve function do not read correctly my url.
I tried to paste the url into the retrieve function like :

```
testfile.retrieve("http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails
/jpg/tn_Quatr_f0.jpg", "tmp/images/full/fish")
```

And it worked perfectly.

```
import urllib
import json

with open('fiche.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    for obj in d:
        name = json.dumps(obj['taxonomy'][0])
        url = json.dumps(obj['image_urls'][0])
        print(name)
        print(url)
        testfile = urllib.URLopener()
        testfile.retrieve(url, "tmp/images/full/fish")
```

I know for the moment it will keep the last pict from my Json i will fix it after resolving this first problem.

JSON :

```
[
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=16520", "taxonomy": ["Quassiremus ascensionis"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_OPHICHT0.gif"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=14873", "taxonomy": ["Quinca mirifica"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_APOGONT0.gif"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=27173", "taxonomy": ["Quassiremus polyclitellum"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_OPHICHT0.gif"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=3896", "taxonomy": ["Quietula y-cauda"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_GOBIIDT0.gif"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=25547", "taxonomy": ["Quassiremus evionthas"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/jpg/tn_Quevi_u0.jpg"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=62532", "taxonomy": ["Quietula guaymasiae"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/jpg/tn_Qugua_u0.jpg"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=13924", "taxonomy": ["Quassiremus nothochir"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/jpg/tn_Qunot_u1.jpg"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=62338", "taxonomy": ["Qianlabeo striatus"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_CYPRINT0.gif"]},
{"fish_url": "http://fishbase.org/Summary/SpeciesSummary.php?id=27728", "taxonomy": ["Quintana atrizona"], "image_urls": ["http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/jpg/tn_Quatr_f0.jpg"]}
]
```

And the result of my request is :

```
"Quassiremus ascensionis"
"http://fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/gif/tn_OPHICHT0.gif"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dlimg.py", line 12, in <module>
    testfile.retrieve(url, "tmp/images/full/fish")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 210, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 222, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '%22http'
```

I search a solution but i spend like 1 hour and did'nt find anything.

Thanks for your answered :)

Comment: can you provide an example of url variable?

Comment: can you also provide a proper solution below. I also stuck in the same problem . I need a reference so i could solve it. What is this testfile.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is " Quotation mark in your url

```
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '%22http'
```

you see %22http

try this

```
testfile.retrieve(url.replace('"',''), "tmp/images/full/fish")
```

i hope it fixes